# Parse error when trying to assign a delegate other than self

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I'm getting a strange error when trying to use `PFLoginViewController` (Parse).

The `PFLoginViewController` class takes a delegate. Here is the class I will delegate to:

```
class AuthenticationController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

It conforms to `PFLogInViewControllerDelegate` which is what Parse is expecting. Here is the controller where I assign the delegate and invoke the login:

```
class MyAccountTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBAction func handleLogInTap(sender: UIButton) {
        let loginViewController = PFLoginViewController()
        loginViewController.delegate = AuthenticationController()
        self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When a login is attempted, the following runs within PFLoginViewController.m (_loginAction):

```
NSString *username = _logInView.usernameField.text ?: @"";
NSString *password = _logInView.passwordField.text ?: @"";

if (_delegateExistingMethods.shouldBeginLogIn) {
    if (![_delegate logInViewController:self shouldBeginLogInWithUsername:username password:password]) {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I `po _logInView.usernameField` I get the correct response:

`<PFTextField: 0x106c1a480; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (0 252; 375 44); text = 'myusername'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b61cad0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ad0eb60>>`

However if I `po username` just after it was set:

`error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of variable username: variable not available
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression`

And the same for `password`. The watchlist shows both as `nil`.

I believe this has something to do with assigning another class as a delegate instead of using `self`. I'm able to get it working by making `MyAccountTableViewController` conform to `PFLogInViewControllerDelegate` and then assigning `self` to the delegate. But I need to break out that login logic to a separate class.

I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `_loginView` - another instance of the `AuthenticationController` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this line is that you create the class `AuthenticationController` and it was released at the end of the function `handleLogInTap`.

```
loginViewController.delegate = AuthenticationController()
```

You need to hold a reference to it in your class `MyAccountTableViewController` and it should be good.

```
private var authentication = AuthenticationController()

@IBAction func handleLogInTap(sender: UIButton) {
    let loginViewController = PFLoginViewController()
    loginViewController.delegate = authentication
    self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I think it's life cycle is until the end of the scope

Comment: @IslamQ. yes, thanks. You are right. I will edit the answer.